# Why cannot Simulink find/run precompiled mexw64 files of the toolboxes?

Tags: matlab, real-time, simulink

[image][image]

I want to run a Simulink model in real time. So I need the Real time sync block in "Simulink desktop real time" (sldrt) toolbox working. It seems to be correctly installed, also in path. But I always get the error:

Error in S-function 'real_time_test/Real-Time Synchronization': Unable to acquire handle to MATLAB function 'sldrtsync'
  Component:Simulink | Category:Blockerror

This error occurs also with the Desktop real time example _sldrtex_vdp_ also see my minimal example that I cannot get working..

In the sldrt directory there are two files:

*sldrtsync.mexw64*

*sldrtsync.tlc*

This path is also included in Matlab Path.

API: Win7 64bit
Matlab R2016b
Windows SDK 7.1

Where to look for the solution?

Comment: It is possible some dependent library or product is not installed. What do you get if you type sldrtsync in the MATLBA command window?

Comment: undefined function or variable 'sldrtsync'

Which I don't understand why. Because the sldrtsync.mexw64 file is in the workspace

Comment: There could be problem with missing dependent libraries or products. I can't think of any other reason.